# Синонимы меток Node.js и React

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

На основном сайте русского Stack Overflow есть две метки — [node.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) и [node](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node). Вероятно стоит вторую сделать синонимом первой, однако репутации по данным меткам, к сожалению, у меня не хватает.

Также есть метки [reactjs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) и [react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) — необходимость их объедения тоже довольно очевидна. При этом, официальное название проекта — [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) (без всяких суффиксов) — соответственно основной меткой должна стать именно [react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), несмотря на её меньшую популярность здесь.

Comment: Метку [tag:node] недавно [удаляли](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1934/)

Comment: @zRrr, как мне кажется, лучше бы всё же сделать синонимом, а не удалять постоянно. `node` - довольно распространенный синоним для `node.js`, судя по выдаче поисковиков. При этом, в техническом русском у этого слова отсутствует двоякое значение, в отличие от технического английского.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov ага, node может быть и узлом графа, и сервером в кластере, но у нас такие значения непопулярны.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Скорей невозможны. Во-первых, я не могу себе представить человека, который будет вместо этих словосочетаний использовать "node", потеряв при переводе ключевое слово. Во-вторых, на SO принято использовать продукт/область-ориентированные метки - однако "узел графа" и "сервер в кластере" это вовсе не название библиотеки, языка программирования, алгоритма, либо какой-то сферы деятельности программиста - соответственно такие словосочетания в метки не попадут. Ну и в-третьих, повторюсь - слово "Node" в техническом русском языке жестко ассоциировано с "Node.js" - так уж повелось.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-нибудь новости про синонимы react и reactjs?